# When training a classifier based on a training set, what should I do if some of the training samples are worth more (are more valuable) than the rest?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, svm, data-science

I am trying to train a classifier based on a given training set (say a 2-class problem with 100 samples per class). How can I train my classifier in a way that some of the samples in the training set (say the first 20 samples from each class) are more valuable than the rest of the samples? (for some reasons, these samples are more similar to the test set, so they should be considered more important in training the classifier) 
Is it ok if I just replicate those samples a couple of times?

I don't know if it matters or not, but my classifier consists of a feature selection step (a filter based method called fast correlation based filter) and a classification step (linear SVM). Also, my test set is a totally different set and I cannot use at all for any step of the training.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok if I just replicate those samples a couple of times?

It depends on the methods you are using. For some - it is fine, like SVM you are refering to - it has additive loss function over samples and does not care about duplicates. **However** this is not how you should approach the problem with SVM, since it directly supports **weighting** of samples, and this is what you should do - attach weight to samples. Depending on the library / language used it might be available or not, but this is the correct way. In libsvm for example you would simply pass `sample_weight` to your `fit` call, like [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html).

Comment: Since I am using a feature selection algorithm before the classification step, I believe it makes more sense to do the example-sensitive trick for both steps.
My feature selection algorithm (called fast correlation based filter) is a filter based method that selects features based on the correlation and information gain of features and classes. Is it ok if I duplicate important samples in that step?

Comment: First check if your method does not have sample weighting implemented since it should be straight forward for method like this. It might still be better to have weighting in svm (even though it makes your code more conplex). As a side note - are you sure that you need this feature selection? It sounds odd, linear svm is pretty good to do it on its own and you will have homogeneous, joint optimization problem